# How do I add a preview image to the analytics template preview?

Tags: einstein-analytics

We have created our own analytics template. I am trying to add a preview image to the analytics template that can be viewed when creating the analytics app from the template. I've tried adding the image file to images folder and into the parent template folder. Neither worked.

Below is the snippet inside the template-info.json. previewDashboard.png is the image name

```
"templatePreviews" : 
      [
        {
        "name": "previewDashboard",
        "label": "Wave Analytics Training",
        "description": "Learn about templates to generate Analytics assets.",
        "namespace": "ssAnalytics"
        }
      ]
```

Answer (score 1):

The images need to be *static resources* in the salesforce instance, rather than part of the analytics template (who thought *that* was a good idea?!)

Next to your **waveTemplates** directory in **force-app/main/default** create a directory called **staticresources** and put your image file in there. Note if it's a JPG it prefers ".jpeg" as a suffix rather than ".jpg".
Also I think that it only allows lower-case names, so your example above wont work.

Create a matching metadata file in the same directory called <myfilename>.resource-meta.xml. E.g. if your image is abc.jpeg, create a file called abc.resource-meta.xml
Add the following content to that metadata file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<StaticResource xmlns="http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata">
    <cacheControl>Public</cacheControl>
    <contentType>image/jpeg</contentType>
</StaticResource>
```

Now you can add the **templatePreview** entry to the **template-info.json** file; the name value should be the file name without its suffix (E.g. "abc" from my example above). The image should not be declared in the **imageFiles** section of **template-info.json**.

You need to deploy to the Org from the **force-app/main/default** level so that it includes the **staticresources** directory.

Hope that helps!

Nick@Sage